# What does Windows XP do at shutdown?

Tags: windows, performance, shutdown

We've all had to wait for Windows to shut down, and some of us have to wait so long that we have to turn off the computer & turn it back on.  Mine usually sits forever on  "Windows is shutting down" (it's there when I come back the next morning!)

So what does Windows actually do that is so important that it needs to hold things up?

Comment: NOT forcibly kill things that don't want to die, in many cases.  
I've had CD-writing software force me to hard-reset, as they locked the drive then crashed. Windows wouldn't reboot!

Comment: I used to have to press enter to finish the shutdown once the disk stopped churning. It seems SOMETHING was prompting for a key press, and you can't see the text console behind the shutting down screen.

Answer (score 5):

It waits for all apps to shut down, it saves all its settings and it probably makes a cup of tea to drink before going to bed :)

On a more serious note, you can read more about the whole shutdown process [here](http://homepages.tesco.net/J.deBoynePollard/FGA/windows-nt-6-shutdown-process.html) (really technical stuff).

Comment: You forgot to mention jam and bread, and on Thursdays, Windows fancies scones too!

Comment: +1 for accurately pointing out that tea is needed.

Comment: @caliban: Go to sleep! :)

Comment: I once had a windows that preferred coffee. Needless to say, I reformatted quickly.

Comment: @alex: wet blanket. ;) Good morrow then, have a great weekend!

Comment: Yeah, my work PC probably drinks redbull all day. I have to kill explorer.exe every time I shut down my PC and then wait a couple of minutes before it figures out I actually want to go home. A couple of times I left work only to find it still shutting down the next day (have no idea what happened).

Comment: @caliban: Thanks, same to you! I'll probably lose my woot badge, unfortunately. Won't be back until Monday :(

Comment: You can't lose something you don't have :·þ ... so you'll just delay the badge :-)

Comment: @Johannes Sad, but true :)

Comment: @alex the fantastic link is dead (more of a reason to always post a snippet of the actual text from the article), can you find it again pretty please?

Answer (score 2):

the **Event Log** is always a good place to start your investigation.

Start > Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Event Viewer

> We've all had to wait for Windows to
>   shut down, and some of us have to wait
>   so long that we have to turn off the
>   computer & turn it back on.

as a workaround (not a solution!) you may resort to **[Superfast Shutdown](http://www.xp-smoker.com/freeware.html)** (it does what it says on the tin).

Comment: I think the corollary is what exactly does Superfast Shutdown do differently, and is it safe?

Comment: it is safe to use. of course, if you're having unsaved documents open, then changes will be lost. mind you, in this case it is a workaround, NOT a solution. however, i'm using SF Reboot regularly with 'DeepFrozen' computers in schools and internet cafes, etc. it works just fine. does what it says on the tin.

Comment: Keep in mind that user programs are pretty much the first to go on shutdown; the mentioned program probably also skips writing the disk cache to disk and other things. You might end up with a slower startup after that while NTFS heals itself

Answer (score 1):

You can set it to force kill any horrible apps - it should shut down within seconds, not days!

Comment: and where is that setting?

Answer (score 0):

Newflash, Walter Cronkite - it's not Windows. It's probably some processes that's having some problems shutting down, and since that processes never shuts down, Windows similarly won't power down too.

A finely-tuned Windows system shuts down really fast.

Answer (score 0):

Windows saves all your settings and everything that you did. [Profile Hive Cleanup](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=1b286e6d-8912-4e18-b570-42470e2f3582&displaylang=en) has helped me with my shutdown, I wonder why no one mentioned it.